# CMake linking error (collect2: ld returned 1 exit status)

Tags: c++, cmake

The project structure below is a simplified example.

```
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── debug
├── CommBase
│   ├── Task.h
│   ├── Task.cpp
│   ├── Thread.h
│   ├── Thread.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── NetWork
│   ├── TSocket.h
│   ├── TSocket.cpp
│   ├── Stream_Channel.h
│   ├── Stream_Channel.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
├── MessageDispatch
│   ├── Channel_Manager.h
│   ├── Channel_Manager.cpp
│   ├── Message_Facade.h
│   ├── Message_Facade.cpp
│   └── CMakeLists.txt
└── DemoServer
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    └── main.cpp
```

***./CMakeLists.txt***

```
PROJECT(DDLIB)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)

MESSAGE(STATUS "This is PROJECT_BINARY_DIR dir "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(CommBase)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(NetWork)
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(DemoServer)
```

***CommBase/CMakeLists.txt***

```
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. LIB_SRC_LIST)
ADD_LIBRARY(CommBase SHARED STATIC ${LIB_SRC_LIST})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../boost)
INSTALL(TARGETS CommBase CommBase
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)

SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O3 -Wall")
```

***NetWork/CMakeLists.txt***

```
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. LIB_SRC_LIST)
ADD_LIBRARY(NetWork SHARED STATIC ${LIB_SRC_LIST})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../boost)
INSTALL(TARGETS NetWork NetWork
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
 TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(NetWork CommBase)
SET( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Debug )
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O0 -Wall -g -ggdb")
SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE "$ENV{CXXFLAGS} -O3 -Wall")
```

***MessageDispatch/CMakeLists.txt***

```
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. LIB_SRC_LIST)
ADD_LIBRARY(MessageDispatch SHARED STATIC ${LIB_SRC_LIST})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../boost)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../CommBase)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../NetWork)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(MessageDispatch CommBase NetWork)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/cl/server/ddsvn/debug)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MessageDispatch CommBase NetWork)
INSTALL(TARGETS MessageDispatch MessageDispatch
LIBRARY DESTINATION lib
ARCHIVE DESTINATION lib)
```

***DemoServer/CMakeLists.txt***

```
PROJECT(DDLIB)
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.6)
MESSAGE(STATUS "This is PROJECT_BINARY_DIR dir "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
SET(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
SET(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
AUX_SOURCE_DIRECTORY(. SRC_LIST)
ADD_EXECUTABLE(DemoServer ${SRC_LIST})
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../boost)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../CommBase)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../NetWork)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(../MessageDispatch)
ADD_DEPENDENCIES(DemoServer CommBase NetWork MessageDispatch)
LINK_DIRECTORIES(/home/cl/server/ddsvn/debug)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(DemoServer CommBase NetWork MessageDispatch)
```

Linking CXX executable DemoServer

```
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/DemoServer.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++     -fPIC CMakeFiles/DemoServer.dir/stdafx.cpp.o CMakeFiles/DemoServer.dir/DemoServer.cpp.o  -o DemoServer -rdynamic -lCommBase -lNetWork -lMessageDispatch 
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message_Facade.cpp.o): In function `Message_Facade::stop()':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message_Facade.cpp:80: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::instance()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message_Facade.cpp:80: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::stop()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message_Facade.cpp.o): In function `Message_Facade::wait()':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message_Facade.cpp:87: undefined reference to `Task::wait()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message_Facade.cpp:88: undefined reference to `Task::wait()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Acceptor_Manager.cpp.o): In function `Stream_Acceptor':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/../NetWork/Stream_Accecptor.h:40: undefined reference to `vtable for Stream_Acceptor'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Channel_Manager.cpp.o): In function `Channel_Manager':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Channel_Manager.cpp:81: undefined reference to `Channel_Handler::~Channel_Handler()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Channel_Manager.cpp.o): In function `~Channel_Manager':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Channel_Manager.cpp:86: undefined reference to `Channel_Handler::~Channel_Handler()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Channel_Manager.cpp:86: undefined reference to `Channel_Handler::~Channel_Handler()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Channel_Manager.cpp.o): In function `Channel_Handler':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/../NetWork/Channel_Handler.h:14: undefined reference to `vtable for Channel_Handler'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Channel_Manager.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI15Channel_Manager[typeinfo for Channel_Manager]+0x28): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Channel_Handler'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message.cpp.o): In function `Message':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:49: undefined reference to `Binary_Stream::Binary_Stream(int)'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:98: undefined reference to `Binary_Stream::~Binary_Stream()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:100: undefined reference to `Binary_Stream::Binary_Stream(int)'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message.cpp.o): In function `Message::resize(int)':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:187: undefined reference to `Stream_Base::resize(int)'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:196: undefined reference to `Stream_Base::resize(int)'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message.cpp.o): In function `~Message':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:203: undefined reference to `Binary_Stream::~Binary_Stream()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Message.cpp:203: undefined reference to `Binary_Stream::~Binary_Stream()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTV7Message[vtable for Message]+0x20): undefined reference to `Stream_Base::clone_stream()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Message.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI7Message[typeinfo for Message]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Binary_Stream'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Connector_Manager.cpp.o): In function `Stream_Connector':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/../NetWork/Stream_Connector.h:42: undefined reference to `vtable for Stream_Connector'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Context.cpp.o): In function `Context':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Context.cpp:15: undefined reference to `Dispatch_Thread::Dispatch_Thread()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Context.cpp.o): In function `Context::initialize()':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Context.cpp:113: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::instance()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Context.cpp:113: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::start()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Context.cpp:116: undefined reference to `Task::activate(int, int*)'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Context.cpp:121: undefined reference to `Task::activate(int, int*)'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(Re_Connect_Handler.cpp.o): In function `Re_Connect_Handler::process_re_connect(Context&, int)':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Re_Connect_Handler.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::instance()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/Re_Connect_Handler.cpp:23: undefined reference to `Timer_Queue::schedule_timer(Smart_Ptr<Timer_Handler>, Time_Value const&, Smart_Ptr<Ref_Object>, EDispatchType, Dispatch_Thread*)'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(IO_Thread.cpp.o): In function `IO_Thread':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/IO_Thread.cpp:4: undefined reference to `Task::Task()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/IO_Thread.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Task::~Task()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(IO_Thread.cpp.o): In function `~IO_Thread':
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/IO_Thread.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Task::~Task()'
/home/cl/server/ddsvn/MessageDispatch/IO_Thread.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Task::~Task()'
/usr/local/lib/libMessageDispatch.a(IO_Thread.cpp.o):(.rodata._ZTI9IO_Thread[typeinfo for IO_Thread]+0x10): undefined reference to `typeinfo for Task'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [DemoServer] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cl/server/ddsvn/DemoServer/Debug'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/DemoServer.dir/all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/cl/server/ddsvn/DemoServer/Debug'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I'm hoping this is a really simple lack of understanding of how CMake handles dependencies. This compiles without error, but fails during linking

NetWork is dependent on CommBase, MessageDispatch dependent on NetWork  and CommBase,how can i specify  in DemoServer

Comment: Read your error message: Linking CXX executable . ;; /usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file .: Is a directory.  You somehow configured a dot to be the name of the application or library, and of course the linker cannot generate a file with that name.

Comment: You shouldn't search for libraries built by yourself, just pass names of their targets to `target_link_library`.

Comment: To see what is really going on you can invoke `make VERBOSE=1` which outputs the actual compiler and linker commands and the concrete arguments that cmake generates.

Comment: Your "simplified example" still is not minimal.  Keep boiling it down until there are only 2-4 files involved, with minimal content, and then we will be in a better position to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues here, some more critical than others.  Roughly in order of importance:

- [`add_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_library) allows you to define the library as *either* `STATIC` or `SHARED`, but not both.
- [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries) links the dependencies in the order they appear in the command.  You should specify them from most-dependent to least.  So, in your DemoServer CMakeLists.txt, it should be

  ```
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(DemoServer MessageDispatch NetWork CommBase)
  ```

  However, from the docs:

  > Library dependencies are transitive by default. When this target is linked into another target then the libraries linked to this target will appear on the link line for the other target too.

  In other words, you should have `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(NetWork CommBase)` in NetWork (you already do), `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(MessageDispatch NetWork)` in MessageDispatch, and just `TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(DemoServer MessageDispatch)` for the Demo.
- [`CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE) would normally be set by the user via the command line (or CMake GUI).  It should probably only be set inside the CMakeLists.txt if the user hasn't already done so, or if it's set to an invalid value.  If you set or change the value, it would be good to tell the user via a `message`.  You probably shouldn't be setting it in 2 different places.
- [`aux_source_directory`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aaux_source_directory) is not recommended as a means to gather lists of source files.  The recommended way is to hard-code the file paths into your CMakeLists.txt, so if the source list changes, CMake automatically re-runs.
- [`link_directories`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3alink_directories) is rarely required, and shouldn't contain a hard-coded absolute path.
- [`LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aLIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH) and [`EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#variable%3aEXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH) are deprecated.
- [`add_dependencies`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.11/cmake.html#command%3aadd_dependencies) is not required if you have already specified these dependencies via a `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: and the syntax error in the static library ^ ^                     thanks A lots